# How to hide the popped UISearchController

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

i'm a beginner in swift. I got a ViewController that contains a TableView.

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

I implemented for the Search the UISearchController and call it with a method:

```
    func search() {
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    userTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

I linked the method search() with an BarButtonItem. The SearchField pops out, but when I want to close it with:

```
    searchController.isActive = false
```

it doesn't close it. Is there a specific way to do it, or did I do something wrong.

Comment: I have used `searchController.isActive = false` today and it worked fine?

Comment: Nope that‘s doesn‘t do anything

Comment: Ah hang on, do you mean that when you tap the button it adds the search bar to the tableView but when you call searchController.isActive = false it doesn't remove the search bar?

Comment: Yea, exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a searchBar to the view but not removing it.

`searchController.isActive = false` just stops the search results view from showing / dismisses it and removes focus from the searchBar

Where you are currently trying to cancel the search, you will also need to remove the search bar from the view hierarchy

```
searchController.isActive = false
userTableView.tableHeaderView = nil
```